# How can i show total number of posts on the home pages in NodeJS and Vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, vue-cli

i want to show the total number of posts available on my web application but i don't know where and how to do this.I am using MongoDB,node js and vue js.
Here is the nodejs code

```
posts.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});
```

VueJS Code

```
  export default {
      data() {
        return {
          posts: [],
        }
      },
      methods: {
        like() {
          title: 'You Just Liked This Post'
          show: true
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        axios
  .get('http://localhost:5000/posts')
  .then(response => (this.posts = response.data))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `posts` is your array of posts once the response is received, you can display the number of posts using javascripts `Array.length` property.

In Vue you can render this directly in the HTML template using `{{ posts.length }}` or if you want to loop through them and actually display the posts, use the `v-for` directive